# Meaning of Kapardin " कपर्दिन् "

Tags: vedas, shiva, rudra

**Lord Rudra** is praised as **Kapardin** in the Ṛgveda and Yajurveda.

The meaning is taken as " Braided hair " or " Matted hair " , what proof do we have that the word **Kapardin** means one having braided or matted hair. And is it really the same as **Jaṭāmukuṭa** of Lord Rudra in post Vedic literature.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: namah kapardine]
Śatarudriya hymns of Yajurveda which often eulogise Lord Rudra with contradictory attributes paired together has:

नमः॑ कप॒र्दिने॑ च॒ व्यु॑प्तकेशाय च॒

namah kapardine ca vyuptakeśāya ca

"Homage to Him [Rudra] of long, braided hair, and to Him of shaven hair"

— Taittirīya Saṃhitā 4.5.5.1, Vājasaneyi Saṃhitā 16.29

Here 'keśa' in 'vyuptakeśāya' makes it perfectly clear that it is about His hair.

All commentators agree on this.

Sāyaṇācārya in his commentary of the Ṛgveda 1.114.5, construes the term kapardin as:

"kapardinaṃ jaṭābhiryuktam"

Uvaṭa on Vājasaneyi Saṃhitā 16.43 takes the term kapardin as:

"kapardī jaṭāmukuṭadhārī"

Commenting on Vājasaneyi Saṃhitā 16.48, Mahīdhara explains the word kapardin thus:

"kapardine jaṭilāya"

Comment: thanks for the answer. Also , what are your views on the epithets " Kṛttivāsā " and " Nīlagrīva " , like does Kṛtti really mean hide and is Nīlagrīva really the same as the "Nīlakanṭha" of the Purāṇas? Because I am confused about the meaning of "Nīla" , does it mean blue or Black or dark ?. And sources other than Commentators , Is Kṛtti used as a word for " Hide " in other Vedic scriptures or other ancient Hindu scriptures? @Śipiviṣṭa